# when adding a new file to a project in VS2013, it changes to a locked state instead of add

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

Using VS2013, and git via Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online), I add a new js file to the project.  The file appears in Source Explorer as expected with the green 'plus' icon.  However, after about 1/2 second or so, it changes to the locked icon.  Hovering over it gives the status of "checked in".  In the Team Explorer tab, the file does not appear in the Included Changes section.  It is not in the Excluded Changes or the Untracked Files sections either.  Bringing up a git bash does not show the file either.  This makes sense since the file is in a checked state - but it doesn't make sense why the file changes from the 'add' status to 'checked in'.  I tried deleting the repository and re-cloning from VSO.  This is a new situation as I have been able to add files in the past - just recently.  Not sure what to make of it.

Comment: This issue can't be reproduced on my side. Are you still able to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the gitignore file had a folder being ignored, which is the folder giving me problems.